# A simple admin panel that changes the text and image

Tags: javascript, node.js, content-management-system, node-modules, admin

I have a site that was created with node js. And I need a ready-made admin panel that will be able to change the text and pictures on the site. I first tried to connect textolite.ru, but then I realized that it will not work. I was offered admin js, keyston js and so on. My site is informative in nature. Therefore, I do not need a complex admin panel. All I need is that on request https://mywebsite/admin I could change the text and image

I need something like textolite.ru. But it doesn't run on node js

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

These options would still require you to write your own authentication, but they do provide a nice, free, open-source wysiwyg editor.

https://quilljs.com/

https://getcontenttools.com/